# the flutter app does not launch FacebookRequestErrorClassification null pointer exception

Tags: flutter, facebook, nullpointerexception

i'm getting this error in the launch of the flutter app, in both release & debug mode.

this started without changing anything.

flutter doctor seems good

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
   at com.facebook.internal.FacebookRequestErrorClassification$Companion.parseJSONDefinition(FacebookRequestErrorClassification.java:6)
   at com.facebook.internal.FacebookRequestErrorClassification$Companion.createFromJSON(FacebookRequestErrorClassification.java:88)
   at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.parseAppSettingsFromJSON$facebook_core_release(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:22)
   at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.loadAppSettingsAsync$lambda-0(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:81)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Check if your Facebook Account is not blocked and the ids are valid

Comment: yes, still valid. in facts it's a global issue, here is the github discussion 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/1179